# talk to VMware virtual machine through real IP

Tags: networking, vmware

---

Dear All,
I have a physical machine running windows server 2008 R2,and windows XP VMWare on the same machine, the physical machine has a real IP. the problem I need to send UDP packets using internet (real IP) to the VMWare. is there a way to redirect the packets to the VMWare or something.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the windows servers firewall to PORT-FORWARD all incoming traffic to port X (the port that info is sent to or choose a random unassigned port) to that IP address.